# R plotly: How to keep width parameter of ggplot2 geom_bar() when using ggplotly()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

For some reason, when converting in R a `ggplot2` bar chart (`geom_bar`) into an interactive plot using `plotly`'s `ggplotly` function, `ggplotly` "forces" the bars to stick together, even if the `width` parameter is specified:

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)

DF <- read.table(text="Rank F1     F2     F3
1    500    250    50
2    400    100    30
3    300    155    100
4    200    90     10", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
DF1 <- melt(DF, id.var="Rank")

p <- ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

```
p <- ggplot(DF1, aes(x = Rank, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.4)

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

It also reverses `ggplot2`s default colors order for some reason (although keeping the order in the legend...), but I can handle this.

Any idea hot to tell `ggplotly` to not stick my bars together, like the default 
`ggplot2` behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea hot to tell ggplotly to not stick my bars together, like the
>   default  ggplot2 behavior?

ggplotly sets `bargap` to `0`, you could set to your desired value via `layout`

```
ggplotly(p) %>% layout(bargap=0.15)
```

[image]

---

> It also reverses ggplot2s default colors order for some reason
>   (although keeping the order in the legend...), but I can handle this.

Let's get that fixed as well. You can change the order afterwards by flipping the bars and reversing the legend.

```
gp <- ggplotly(p) %>% layout(bargap = 0.15, legend = list(traceorder = 'reversed'))

traces <- length(gp[['x']][[1]])
for (i in 1:floor(traces / 2)) {
  temp <- gp[['x']][[1]][[i]]
  gp[['x']][[1]][[i]] <- gp[['x']][[1]][[traces + 1 - i]]
  gp[['x']][[1]][[traces + 1 - i]] <- temp
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you know why ggplotly changes color order and how to deal with it? Currently I use the reverse color order in the original ggplot2 graph, that's how I get the color order I wanted - but that's an ugly solution.

Comment: @GioraSimchoni: see updated answer for an alternative approach