# ggplotly preserve two categorical legends ggplot R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

**Edit**

It turns out this is still a dupe of that question...several years later.

**Original question**

This is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820823/r-plotly-preserving-appearance-of-two-legends-when-converting-ggplot2-with-ggpl), but that is a few years old and was not easy to find.

Basically when ggplotly translates a ggplot2 plot, it combines the two legends and creates one combined legend that is not that usable.

Repeatable example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
data(mtcars)
#two separate legends, as expected
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, 
                       colour = factor(am), shape = factor(carb))) +
  geom_point()

#one combined, not-usable legend.
ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Ok, what are you after here? Should we close as dupe then?

Comment: @axeman - Essentially an updated answer to that question, but given the amount of development in both ggplot2 and plot_ly over the past two years - it's not really a dupe in my mind.

Comment: Does that answer still work (I know it's rather verbose)?

Comment: Perhaps you can just put a fat bounty on that one.

Comment: Having two separate legends is not possible in Plotly as far as I know, but at least one could group the legends.

Comment: @Axeman: the answer to the linked question is still working with latest plotly version (just tested it).