# Is there a way to show a legend in plot_ly similar to how it appears when using ggplot?

Tags: r, r-plotly, ggplotly

```
set.seed(123)
student.name <- rep(c("Annie","Jane","Bobby","Tyson"),each=16)
year <- rep(c(2007,2008,2009,2010),each=4,times=4)
period <- rep(c("First","Second","Third","Fourth"),times=16)
grades <- round(runif(64,min=60,max=100),0)
df <- data.frame(student.name,year,period,grades)

mygraph <- df %>% ggplot(aes(x=year,y=grades,color=student.name,group=interaction(student.name,period))) + 
  geom_line(aes(linetype=period))
ggplotly(mygraph)
```

I created a sample of data above to try and demonstrate the issue/problem I'm trying to solve.

In ggplot, the legend shows 8 items, each of the periods and each of the student names. However when I apply ggplotly, the legend shows all 16 with the label (period, student.name). I prefer the way the legend is shown in ggplot, is there a way to change this using ggplotly? Would I have to use plot_ly to have the option to make this change? I wasn't sure how to do this in plot_ly if that's the route I should take.

See below for the images:

[ggplot created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPXx4.png)

[ggplotly applied to ggplot above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPXKM.png)

Thanks!

Comment: So if ggplot does what you inquire, why add ggplotly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820823/r-plotly-preserving-appearance-of-two-legends-when-converting-ggplot2-with-ggpl