# Change alpha based on factor group in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

```
dftt <- data.frame(values = runif(27, min = 0, max = 1),
                   
                   Position_Group = c("Detroit.1-3", "Detroit.1-3", "Detroit.1-3",  
                                  "Detroit.4-6",  "Detroit.4-6",  "Detroit.4-6",
                                   "Detroit.7-9",  "Detroit.7-9",  "Detroit.7-9",
                                  "Chicago.1-3", "Chicago.1-3", "Chicago.1-3",
                                  "Chicago.4-6", "Chicago.4-6", "Chicago.4-6",
                                  "Chicago.7-9","Chicago.7-9","Chicago.7-9",
                                   "Atlanta.1-3", "Atlanta.1-3", "Atlanta.1-3",
                                  "Atlanta.4-6","Atlanta.4-6","Atlanta.4-6",
                                  "Atlanta.7-9","Atlanta.7-9","Atlanta.7-9"),
                                  
                   name = c("Detroit", "Detroit", "Detroit",
                            "Detroit", "Detroit", "Detroit",
                            "Detroit","Detroit","Detroit",
                            "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
                            "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
                            "Chicago","Chicago","Chicago",
                            "Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Atlanta",
                            "Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Atlanta",
                            "Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Atlanta"),
                   
                   x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))

dftt$Position_Group <- as.factor(dftt$Position_Group)

levels <- unique(dftt$Position_Group)
dftt$Position_Group <- factor(dftt$Position_Group, levels = levels)
dftt <- dftt[order(dftt$Position_Group),]
   
 dataset2 <- dftt %>%
        ggplot(aes(x=x, y=values, group = Position_Group , color = name, alpha = Position_Group)) + geom_line(size = 3) +
        scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1, 0.4, 0.1))
 
 dataset2
```

I am attempting to change the alpha value for each factor group. For example, I want Detroit.1-3 to be the darkest, Detroit.4-6 to be the second darkest, and Detroit.7-9 to be the lightest. I would like to apply this to Chicago and Atlanta as well. I've provided my code above, but unfortunately, it seems like this only works for 2 of the city names, while the third city's alpha values are unchanged. Any ideas on how I can tweak my code to achieve the desired outcome? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  If so, the answer is splitting off the group values from the city names.  I did this using `separate()`.  Then you can map `alpha` to this new `group` variables.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
dftt <- data.frame(values = runif(27, min = 0, max = 1),
                   
                   Position_Group = c("Detroit.1-3", "Detroit.1-3", "Detroit.1-3",  
                                      "Detroit.4-6",  "Detroit.4-6",  "Detroit.4-6",
                                      "Detroit.7-9",  "Detroit.7-9",  "Detroit.7-9",
                                      "Chicago.1-3", "Chicago.1-3", "Chicago.1-3",
                                      "Chicago.4-6", "Chicago.4-6", "Chicago.4-6",
                                      "Chicago.7-9","Chicago.7-9","Chicago.7-9",
                                      "Atlanta.1-3", "Atlanta.1-3", "Atlanta.1-3",
                                      "Atlanta.4-6","Atlanta.4-6","Atlanta.4-6",
                                      "Atlanta.7-9","Atlanta.7-9","Atlanta.7-9"),
                   
                   name = c("Detroit", "Detroit", "Detroit",
                            "Detroit", "Detroit", "Detroit",
                            "Detroit","Detroit","Detroit",
                            "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
                            "Chicago", "Chicago", "Chicago",
                            "Chicago","Chicago","Chicago",
                            "Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Atlanta",
                            "Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Atlanta",
                            "Atlanta", "Atlanta", "Atlanta"),
                   
                   x = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3))

dftt$Position_Group <- as.factor(dftt$Position_Group)

levels <- unique(dftt$Position_Group)
dftt$Position_Group <- factor(dftt$Position_Group, levels = levels)
dftt <- dftt[order(dftt$Position_Group),]

dftt %>%
  separate(Position_Group, into=c("city", "group"), sep = "\\.") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=values,color = name, alpha = group)) + geom_line(size = 3) +
  scale_alpha_discrete(range = c(1, 0.4, 0.1))
#> Warning: Using `size` aesthetic for lines was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
#> ℹ Please use `linewidth` instead.
#> Warning: Using alpha for a discrete variable is not advised.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This works perfectly! However, my legend isn't as clean as yours. I am actually converting my ggplot to plotly using the ggplotly function. So, my legend says (p1-3 Detroit, p1-3 Atlanta, p1-3 Chicago, p4-6 Detroit, p4-6 Chicago, etc.) -- is there any way I can make the legend look like yours in plotly if you happen to know?

Comment: Looks like it might be a bit complicated, though there is a discussion of something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820823/r-plotly-preserving-appearance-of-two-legends-when-converting-ggplot2-with-ggpl).